# Python check if value exists inside a json array

Tags: python, json

I have the following python script

```
def main():
    json_obj = {
        "attributes": [
            {
                "key": "some key",
                "value": "hello"
            }
        ]
    }

    needle = "hello"
    if needle in json_obj["attributes"]:
        print("yay")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now i don't understand why the print statement returns false. surely needle is in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate but you are doing an in check in a dictionary which on default only checks the keys:

```
"key" in  {"key": "some key", "value": "hello"}
```

will yield false since it is similar to:

```
"key" in  {"key": "some key", "value": "hello"}.keys()
```

whereas

```
"hello" in  {"key": "some key", "value": "hello"}.values()
```

will yield True

Comment: `json_obj["attributes"]` is a list of dict.

Comment: ... so there are two errors and you would require an additional check

Comment: as @ekhumoro said - correct check is `if needle in json_obj["attributes"][0].values()`

Comment: @Crunchie The question is ill-defined. Is the search really for ***any*** value that equals `needle`? It seems more likely that the OP wants to find the element for which "value" equals `needle`.